# Simulation of Rocket chambers like in Hall Effect Thrusters

Tags: propulsion, engine-design, software, ion-thruster

I started learning [Solidworks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SolidWorks) in  hopes of being able to run simulation  to study  rocket chambers.  Currently, I am studying the flow of plasma and its  interaction with the magnetic  field,  but found that,  Solid works does  not have that  feature. or, can I just use Matlab  for  this?

If you  are  aware  of this  field, could  you please recommend me the  software to use.

Some names I came across were [ANSYS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ansys) and [COMSOL Multiphysics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COMSOL_Multiphysics), but would like to know if there is something better.

Thank you.

Comment: This is quite a lot of territory to cover in one question! You are welcome to ask as many questions here as you like, so I would recommend you focus on the plasma and magnetic field in this question, and ask about chemical rocket combustion chambers in your next question.

Comment: Ion/plasma simulators built into cad programs are pretty rare; you'll probably find it easier to find a standalone ion optics program.

Some possibilities:

 - SIMION - only for organizations with deep, deep pockets.
 - MaxFEM - good for the magnetic field, anyway. I've also had good results with http://www.falstad.com/emstatic/fullscreen.html. Probably not exactly what you're looking for, but hopefully enough to get you started. Might want to try asking at physics.stackexchange, too.